# Want to use Jasmine HTML reporter along with the Protractor HTML reporter

Tags: protractor

i have tried to use Jasmine HTML reporter along with the Protractor HTML reporter.

My Config.js code look like this

```
    var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: '/protractor-result', 
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
}));


var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
    savePath: '../Report/HTML/',
    showSummary: true,
    showQuickLinks: true,
    showConfiguration: true,
    screenshotsFolder: 'images',
    takeScreenshots: true,
    takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
    fixedScreenshotName: true,
    ignoreSkippedSpecs: true,
    consolidate: true,
    consolidateAll: true,
    preserveDirectory: true,
    reportTitle: 'Protractor-Execution-Report-' + timeStamp
}));
```

i could able to see HTML reports generated by Jasmine but still unable to see the HTML reports generated by Protractor.Please correct me if i am trying something unreal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**protractor-html-screenshot-reporter** is not compatible with **jasmine 2** and latest version of protractor uses jasmine 2 by default, instead switch to

> protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter

Comment: @Shailendra here's your answer

Comment: thanks for sharing this but would like to keep this thread on so that if anyone else gets any idea in this context can update. thanks again.

Comment: Sure you could accept the answer if it solves your issue! The thread will always be open since it is in open forum:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put those lines inside your onPrepare section of the `protractor.config.js` file:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');


exports.config = {
   //other stuff

   onPrepare: function() {
      // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screnshots`: 
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'
         //...
      }));
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
         savePath: '../Report/HTML/'
         //...
      }));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

i have used those lines of code inside my onPrepare() function only, Please have a look below


onPrepare: function () { 
  
 jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
     baseDirectory: '/protractor-result', 
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
}));
     
   }

still im unable to see the HTML reports generated.

i could see the HTML reports if using them alone but with Jasmine reporter unable to do so, is this possible to generate both Spect level and Expect level reporters.

Answer (score 1):

I use `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` and `protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter` to handle that, here is my configuration file `protractor.conf.js`, hope it can help you.

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var jasmine2HtmlReporter =  new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
  savePath: 'report/e2e/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter/',
  filePrefix: 'index',
  screenshotsFolder: 'screenshots'
});

var htmlScreenshotReporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'report/e2e/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/',
  filename: 'index.html'
});

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    '*.e2e.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/app/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    showColors: true
  },

  // Setup the report before any tests start
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      htmlScreenshotReporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
  },

  // Assign the test reporter to each running instance
  onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(jasmine2HtmlReporter);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(htmlScreenshotReporter);
  },

  // Close the report after all tests finish
  afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      htmlScreenshotReporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
  }

};
```

For details you see [here](https://github.com/chendachao/angular-seed)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old, but I ran into an issue trying to get jasmine-reporters and protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter to work and didn't like the idea that I had to downgrade in order for them to work. I found out that protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter wasn't resolving the savePath correctly and was actually putting the reports folder output in protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter directory instead of the root directory of where I ran gulp. In order to make this work correctly I ended up using **process.env.INIT_CWD** to get the initial Current Working Directory which should be the directory where you ran gulp. Hope this helps someone.

```js
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var jasmine2HtmlReporter = new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
  savePath: process.env.INIT_CWD + '/report/e2e/',
  screenshotsFolder: 'images',
  takeScreenshots: true,
  takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
  fileName: 'index.html'
});

onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(jasmine2HtmlReporter);
}
```